# Mysql locale session variable?

Tags: mysql, internationalization

Hunting internationalization bugs here.

Does mysql has a variable which can be set per session, meaning the each connection will know the timezone of it's client and will act upon that.

If such variable does exists I would expect sql statements such as the following will return diffect values, based on connection session locale.

```
select date('2010-04-14') + 0;
```

Thank you,
Maxim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DATE() function in MySQL returns server time unless you specify the timezone.

CONVERT_TZ() is useful. Let the user pick their time zone and store it on the server, then convert the date columns to the user's time.

There is a time_zone system variable that you can set for a session, which defaults to "SYSTEM".

Use `SET @@variable` to set the value.

For example:

```
SET @@time_zone = 'GMT';
```

However, the server doesn't automatically set this based on the location or timezone of the client.